# Rails 4 with Simple Form - CSS problems

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I have a rails 4 app with simple form and bootstrap.

I have this input:

```
       <%= f.label  'Does this project require ethics approval?',   :class => 'subquestion' %>
```

I have defined a css subquestion field as:

```
.subquestion {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #7491A3;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

When I inspect the element, the first three attributes of my CSS styling are struck out. The google inspector shows that the closest CSS styling applied is called string optional control label subquestion. I don't know where that class is defined.

Does anyone know how to apply css to simple form in rails bootstrap?

Thank you

Comment: theyre struck out because there are other styles in your stylesheet that have higher importance than the ones you specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either re-organize the order the css is being loaded in the Sass or append !important to the styles being crossed out. The former is the better option long term.

Make sure Bootstrap is being loaded before the rest of your css

Such as:

```
/*
*= require bootstrap.min.css
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*/
```

Another option is the SASS import rules

https://content.pivotal.io/blog/structure-your-sass-files-with-import